# Page reload not reflecting database updates

Tags: javascript, spring

I have a dropdown list on an update agent profile form where a user can select an item, referred to as a "master" in the database. However, if they select the item "Create New Master", they can enter a value in a blank text field and click a corresponding button. This updates the "Create New Master" value in the database to be whatever the value they entered is, and creates a new value in the database as the new "Create New Master" value. This also updates the agent table in the database to have the new master's ID saved to it, changing whatever the previous ID was. All of the database functionality works, and all the changes are made. However, I need to reload the form with the new values. How can I reload this? We use spring and hibernate, but I'm using Javascript for most of the functionality on this form page.

I've tried using window.location.reload(true), but this doesn't work. If the page kicks the user from the profile and then the user manually re-enters the profile of the same agent, the updated values show, but this is obviously less than ideal.

```
function addMaster(obj){
    //Create lots of relevant variables that are used for the database update.
    if(newName == null || newName == ""){
        alert("You have to enter a new name to add it.");
    }
    else{
        var jsonURL = '${urlBase}/addMaster/' + newName + '/' + updated + '/' + updateID + '/' + created + '/' + createID + '/' + create + '/' + agentID + '.json?jsoncallback=?';
        var xhttp = jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function(obj, textStatus){

        });
    window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

This calls to another file, which updates the database accordingly and correctly, but the reload doesn't change the new selection in the dropdown list. It shows the old one, even though checking the database shows that it has truly been updated. How can I make the current database values be reflected on the page without having to make the user leave the profile?

Answer (score 0):

The method `jQuery.getJSON` is asynch so you reload the page before the call is completed. You should reload the page after that you request completed so you should do something like this:

```
function addMaster(obj){
    //Create lots of relevant variables that are used for the database update.
    if(newName == null || newName == ""){
        alert("You have to enter a new name to add it.");
    }
    else{
        var jsonURL = '${urlBase}/addMaster/' + newName + '/' + updated + '/' + updateID + '/' + created + '/' + createID + '/' + create + '/' + agentID + '.json?jsoncallback=?';
        var xhttp = jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function(obj, textStatus){
                  //this is the success function.. asynch call is done
                  window.location.reload(true);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the data on dB change?

Comment: I just checked again to be sure, and it does.